# Regex for device vendor extraction from SNMP list

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a script which extracts from devices their SysObject OID and bind it into the variable. For example:

```
echo $device_manufacturer
1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78.device
```

And, have a list of devices and their relevant SNMP OIDs in file. Example:

```
/usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/hp/procurve/1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.72.device:    <id>1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.72</id>
/usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/cisco/router/1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.864.device:    <id>1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.864</id>
/usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/alcatel/omniswitch7000/1.3.6.1.4.1.6486.800.1.1.2.1.3.1.3.device:    <id>1.3.6.1.4.1.6486.800.1.1.2.1.3.1.3</id>
/usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/hp/procurve/1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78.device:    <id>1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78</id>
```

So, for 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78.device the vendor will be HP.
And the path is always the same: /usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/"VENDOR_NAME"/"DEVICE_NAME"/"SNMP_OID".

Is there any way to write regex, which returns me name of a vendor, if I know SNMP OID?

Comment: use `grep -oP "[^/]+(?=/[^/]+/$device_manufacturer)"` if `pcre` regex is available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is so straightforward that you don't need regex for this. The following should suffice:

```
grep -F $device_manufacturer myfile.txt | cut -d'/' -f7
```

Comment: Indeed very straightforward approach. Didn't think about this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain, what means -d'/' -f7 ?

Comment: `-d'/'` means cut the matching line, which would be `/usr/tideway/data/installed/devices/hp/procurve/1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78.device:    <id>1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.7.11.78</id>`, with delimiter `/`. `-f7` means pick the 7th entry from the result.

Comment: probably not required in this case, but using `-F` option for `grep` would be better as it will interpret the string literally and not as regex... also, quote variables as good practice...

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` to find the line, then `sed` to extract it:

```
grep $device_manufacturer myfile.txt | sed 's_.*/devices/\([^/]*\)/.*_\1_'
```